# How do I get the last and second last inserted data of a certain user in table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create table table_1(user_id int, bmi int, date date)

Insert into table_1(user_id, bmi ,date) values (1, '20', '2020-05-01'),
                                       (1, '25', '2020-05-10'),
                                       (1, '30', '2020-05-20');
```

Here I want to retrieve the two latest inserted 'bmi' of user '1' so that I can compare his improvements,etc. 
The result should give me the 'bmi' of dates 2020-05-10 and 2020-05-20

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: `SELECT bmi FROM table_1 WHERE user_id=1 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 2;`

Comment: Why would you not want the query to calculate the change for you?

Comment: I want to retrieve it for inserting into php file @P.Salmon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution (only works in MYSQL 8.0):

```
SELECT bmi FROM 
(
SELECT *
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date DESC) row_num
FROM input_table
)
WHERE user_id = 1 AND row_num <= 2;
```

Solution 2 works in any MySQL version:

```
SELECT bmi
FROM input_table
WHERE user_id = 1
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: Simple solution, which also works in 8.0: `SELECT bmi FROM table_1 WHERE user_id=1 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 2;`

Comment: Ya that is right Luuk I am not denying. I am just giving a different way of writing the query

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer:
SELECT bmi FROM table_1 WHERE user_id=1 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 2;
credits: @Luuk